# my app is crash on ios14 App crash on splash Screen in flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, ios14

**issue in old build**

**i have build my flutter ios build with Debug so it will crash on ios 14 new major release**

Answer (score 2):

Change Debug to release in Build, Run, Test, Analyze from Edit Scheme

[image]

Due to low-level changes in iOS’s debugger mechanisms, developers using versions of Flutter earlier than 1.20.4 stable won’t be able to launch apps (by using flutter run or a Flutter-enabled IDE) on physical iOS devices running iOS 14. This affects debug, profile, and release builds. Simulator builds, add-to-app modules, and running directly from Xcode are unaffected.

Upgrading to Flutter 1.22 beta allows you to build, test, and deploy to iOS without issue. Upgrading to 1.20.4 stable allows you to build and deploy to iOS 14, but not debug.

Comment: I add the same problem now... could you fix this?